# Effective way to encourage users to improve posts

Tags: discussion

After trying to encourage a newer user to improve and describe their [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30194355/access-textbox-from-another-class) for the umpteenth time today I'm starting to wonder if my approach is perhaps too heavy handed and in fact deterring potentially decent contributors away from the site. (I've linked to the question purely to show an example of this).

I haven't actually found a question in two weeks that I felt either was already a duplicate of another question or of a quality that should really be encouraged with an answer (excluding those that I didn't know enough about to actually answer).

So, I am asking here on meta for active critique from anyone that has constructive criticism on my approach on this or any other of my recent activity that they have noticed as to how I could possibly improve.

In order to construct this into a more constructive question.... Has anyone discovered an effective method to encourage a user to improve their question to be more along with the Stack Overflow guidelines?

Comment: That specific instance, I don't think any approach would encourage the user who says ["I did not understand what I found. Could you give me a solution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30194355/access-textbox-from-another-class#comment48494161_30194355) to improve the post drastically.

Comment: Indeed, knowing when to just give up on a hopeless case is very important.

Comment: Not sure.  If I find a 'potentially decent contributor', I will ask them:(